# Can you auto load an href without having to click something?

Tags: php, html

I want to activate this href

```
<p><a class="button" href="#popup1">Click Me</a></p>
```

without having to use the button. So for example,

```
if ($info == "this") {
            //go to href=#popup1 here
}
```

I tried doing this,

```
if ($info == "this") {
            print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=#popup1' />";
}
```

but it just gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: Yes you can using `.click()` function

Comment: I did some research into that and I think you have to use javascript for that? I'm trying to use only HTML or PHP, anyway to do that?

Comment: I think below answer will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping some id to your `a` tag, you can achieve this by `.click()` function

```
<p><a class="button" id="popup1" href="#popup1">Click Me</a></p>


if (true /*your logic*/) {
   echo '<script>document.getElementById("popup1").click()</script>';
}
```

Comment: this does work, but is there any way to do it without the use of javascript?

Comment: May be we can't without `js`